# TCPDF shows only first record from DB and not showing other record

Tags: php, pdf

I want to convert a view file into pdf.. View file have records coming from db... but when its render to pdf, no data shows from where php variable comes..
Can anyone suggest what is the issue:

After "company" displayed its showing blank pdf

Here is pdf creating code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
                require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');        
                $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
                $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
                $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
                $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
                $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
                $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
                $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
                $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
                if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
                    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
                    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
                }
                $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
                $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
                $html = $this->load->view('frontend/quotes_detail_po_pdf', $data, TRUE);
                $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
                ob_end_clean();
                $pdf->Output($prorder.".pdf", 'I');
```

**VIEW FILE:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 nopad">
            <div class="col-xs-5 nopad qts">
                <h2>Purchase Request Details</h2>
                <table width="100%" border="0" class="qtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <th width="40%">Company</th>
                  <td width="2%">:
                    </th>
                  <td width="585"><?php echo $compdata[0]->name;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Department</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $deprow[0]->department;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Referrence #</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $pritem[0]->pReference;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Request Created</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php if($pritem[0]->pCreated != ""){echo date("F, d Y - h:i A",strtotime($pritem[0]->pCreated));}?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Approved By</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php if($pritem[0]->pApproveBy == 0){}else { echo $approve[0]->first_name." ".$approve[0]->last_name;} ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Approved Date</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php if($pritem[0]->pApproveDate != ""){echo date("F, d Y - h:i A",strtotime($pritem[0]->pApproveDate));}?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php if($pritem[0]->pApproved == 0){echo "<strong style='color:#f00'>Pending</strong>";}else { echo "<strong style='color:#109D00;'>Approved</strong>";} ?></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 qts">
              <h2>Vendor Details</h2>
              <table width="100%" border="0" class="qtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <th width="40%">Vendor Name</th>
                  <td width="2%">:
                    </th>
                  <td width="585"><?php echo $vendorsdata[0]->displayName;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $vendorsdata[0]->cEmail;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Contact #</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $vendorsdata[0]->cMobile;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Billing Address</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $vendorsdata[0]->cAttention;?> <?php if($vendorsdata[0]->cStreet!= ""){echo ",".$vendorsdata[0]->cStreet;}?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>City/Location</th>
                  <td>:</td>
                  <td><?php echo $vendorsdata[0]->cCity;?> <?php if($vendorsdata[0]->cState!= ""){echo ",".$vendorsdata[0]->cState;}?> <?php if($vendorsdata[0]->cZip!= ""){echo ",".$vendorsdata[0]->cZip;}?> <?php if($vendorsdata[0]->cCountry!= ""){echo ",".$vendorsdata[0]->cCountry;}?></td>
                </tr>

              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```